# GridView Hide Column by code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to hide ID column in my GridView, I knew the code

```
GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

but the surprise was that my count property for my `GridView` columns is 0 !!! while I can see data in the `GridView`, so any ideas?

Thank you,

Update:

here is the complete code for the method which populate the `GridView`

```
public DataSet GetAllPatients()
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString);

    String sql = "SELECT [ID],[Name],[Age],[Phone],[MedicalHistory],[Medication],[Diagnoses] FROM [dbo].[AwadyClinc_PatientTbl]order by ID desc";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    da.Fill(ds);

    return ds;

}
```

Comment: your binding  GridView by datatable? please add your code here

Comment: GridView1.DataSource = patientObj.GetAllPatients().Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: while GetAllPatients() is a method which returns DataSet object

Comment: add empty data tamplate to grid view see if the *patientObj.GetAllPatients().Tables[0]* is returning blank data table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide a column (GridView) but still access its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376278/how-to-hide-a-column-gridview-but-still-access-its-value)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`GridView.Columns.Count` will always be 0 when your GridView has its `AutoGenerateColumns` property set to `true` (default is `true`).

You can explicitly declare your columns and set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `false`, or you can use this in your codebehind:

`GridView.Rows[0].Cells.Count`

to get the column count once your GridView data has been bound, or this:

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[index].Visible = false;
}
```

to set a column invisible using your GridView's `RowDataBound` event.

Answer (score 34):

This helped for me

```
this.myGridview.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

Here 0 is the column index i want to hide.

Comment: But what if you wanted to hide controls in that column and still have access to them in code behind? .Visible literally removes it from the DOM. What we need is a style="display:none".

Comment: @Fandango68...Exactly! I was coloring text in RowDataBound and needed this particular field to exist and be hidden.

Comment: You can do it this way too.
this.myGridview.Columns["columnName"].Visible = false;

Comment: On Row DataBound Make Sure Its DataRow.                                                              
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                    gridviewid.Columns[1].Visible = false;
                }

Answer (score 28):

You can hide a specific  column by querying the datacontrolfield collection for the desired column header text and setting its visibility to true.

```
((DataControlField)gridView.Columns
               .Cast<DataControlField>()
               .Where(fld => (fld.HeaderText == "Title"))
               .SingleOrDefault()).Visible = false;
```

Comment: The above worked the best for me.  Setting row.cells[x].Visible = false just caused my columns to shift while the headers stayed in place.

Answer (score 13):

Some of the answers I've seen explain how to make the contents of a cell invisible, but not how to hide the entire column, which is what I wanted to do.

If you have `AutoGenerateColumns = "false"` and are actually using `BoundField` for the column you want to hide, Bala's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3819578/154637) is slick.  But if you are using `TemplateField` for the column, you can handle the `DataBound` event and do something like this:

```
protected void gridView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const int countriesColumnIndex = 4;

    if (someCondition == true)
    {
        // Hide the Countries column
        this.gridView.Columns[countriesColumnIndex].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

This may not be what the OP was looking for, but it's the solution I was looking for when I found myself asking the same question.

Answer (score 3):

Here i am binding the gridview with dataset like this-

```
GVAnswer.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
GVAnswer.DataBind();
```

Then after

Then we count the number of rows
like this in the for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < GVAnswer.Rows.Count; i++)
{

}
```

Then after we find the header we want make visible false

```
GVAnswer.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Visible = false;
```

then after we make the visibility false of that particular cell.

The complete code is give like this

`public void FillGVAnswer(int QuestionID)
{
    try
    {


        OBJClsQuestionAnswer = new ClsQuestionAnswer();
        DS = new DataSet();
        DS = OBJClsQuestionAnswer.GetAnswers(QuestionID);

        GVAnswer.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
        GVAnswer.DataBind();
        if (DS.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {



            for (int i = 0; i < GVAnswer.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                GVAnswer.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Visible = false;
                GVAnswer.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Visible = false;
                GVAnswer.HeaderRow.Cells[6].Visible = false;

                GVAnswer.HeaderRow.Cells[8].Visible = false;

                GVAnswer.HeaderRow.Cells[10].Visible = false;

                GVAnswer.HeaderRow.Cells[11].Visible = false;


                //GVAnswer.Rows[i].Cells[1].Visible = false;
                if (GVAnswer.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text == "T")
                {
                    GVAnswer.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text = "Text";
                }
                else
                {
                    GVAnswer.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text = "Image";
                }
                if (GVAnswer.Rows[i].Cells[5].Text == "View Image")
                {
                    HtmlAnchor a = new HtmlAnchor();
                    a.HRef = "~/ImageHandler.aspx?ACT=AIMG&AID=" + GVAnswer.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
                    a.Attributes.Add("rel", "lightbox");
                    a.InnerText = GVAnswer.Rows[i].Cells[5].Text;

                    GVAnswer.Rows[i].Cells[5].Controls.Add(a);
                }

                if (GVAnswer.Rows[i].Cells[7].Text == "Yes")
                {
                    j++;
                    ViewState["CheckHasMulAns"] = j;// To Chek How Many answer Of a particulaer Question Is Right
                }

                GVAnswer.Rows[i].Cells[8].Visible = false;
                GVAnswer.Rows[i].Cells[3].Visible = false;
                GVAnswer.Rows[i].Cells[10].Visible = false;
                GVAnswer.Rows[i].Cells[6].Visible = false;
                GVAnswer.Rows[i].Cells[11].Visible = false;
                GVAnswer.Rows[i].Cells[2].Visible = false;

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string err = ex.Message;
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            err = err + " :: Inner Exception :- " + ex.InnerException.Message;
        }
        string addInfo = "Error in getting Answers :: -> ";
        ClsExceptionPublisher objPub = new ClsExceptionPublisher();
        objPub.Publish(err, addInfo);
    }
}`

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna hide that column while grid populating, you can do it in aspx page itself like this

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="test" HeaderText="test" Visible="False" />
```

Comment: This is not a solution if the developer sets AutoGenerateColumns="true"

Answer (score 2):

```
 private void Registration_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

                        //hiding data grid view coloumn
                        datagridview1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                            datagridview1.DataSource =dataSet;
                            datagridview1.DataMember = "users"; //  users is table name
                            datagridview1.Columns[0].Visible = false;//hiding 1st coloumn coloumn
                            datagridview1.Columns[2].Visible = false; hiding 2nd coloumn
                            datagridview1.Columns[3].Visible = false; hiding 3rd coloumn
                        //end of hiding datagrid view coloumns

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide a column by its name instead of its index in GridView. After creating DataTable or Dataset, you have to find the index of the column by its name then save index in global variable like ViewStae, Session and etc and then call it in RowDataBound, like the example:

```
string headerName = "Id";
        DataTable dt = .... ;

        for (int i=0;i<dt.Columns.Count;i++)
        {
            if (dt.Columns[i].ColumnName == headerName)
            {
                ViewState["CellIndex"] = i;

            }

        }

  ... GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header || e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow || e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {

        int index = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["CellIndex"]);

        e.Row.Cells[index].Visible = false;
    }                        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What most answers here don't explain is - what if you need to make columns visible again and invisible, all based on data dynamically? After all, shouldn't `GridViews` be data centric?

What if you want to turn ON or OFF columns based on your data?

My `Gridview`

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvLocationBoard" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" ShowFooter="false" ShowHeader="true" Visible="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
            DataSourceID="sdsLocationBoard" OnDataBound="gvLocationBoard_DataBound" OnRowDataBound="gvLocationBoard_RowDataBound" PageSize="15" OnPreRender="gvLocationBoard_PreRender">
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="StudentID" SortExpression="StudentID" Visible="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StudentID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Student" SortExpression="StudentName">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StudentName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="CheckStatusName" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfStatusID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CheckStatusID") %>' />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CheckStatusName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RollCallPeriod0" Visible="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbRollCallPeriod0" runat="server" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfRollCallPeriod0" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("RollCallPeriod") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Size="Small" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RollCallPeriod1" Visible="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbRollCallPeriod1" runat="server" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfRollCallPeriod1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("RollCallPeriod") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Size="Small" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
        ..
etc..
```

Note the `"RollCallPeriodn", where 'n' is a sequential number.

The way I do it, is to by design **hide all columns** that I know are going to be ON (visible="true") or OFF (visible="false") later, and depending on my data.

In my case I want to display Period Times up to a certain column. So for example, if today is 9am then I want to show periods 6am, 7am, 8am and 9am, **but not** 10am, 11am, etc.

On other days I want to show ALL the times. And so on.

So how do we do this?

Why not use `PreRender` to "reset" the `Gridview`?

```
protected void gvLocationBoard_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
    int wsPos = 3;
    for (int wsCol = 0; wsCol < 19; wsCol++)
    {
        gv.Columns[wsCol + wsPos].HeaderText = "RollCallPeriod" + wsCol.ToString("{0,00}");
        gv.Columns[wsCol + wsPos].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Now turn ON the columns you need based on finding the Start of the HeaderText and make the column visible **if the header text is not the default.**

```
  protected void gvLocationBoard_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Show the headers for the Period Times directly from sdsRollCallPeriods
        DataSourceSelectArguments dss = new DataSourceSelectArguments();
        DataView dv = sdsRollCallPeriods.Select(dss) as DataView;
        DataTable dt = dv.ToTable() as DataTable;
        if (dt != null)
        {
            int wsPos = 0;
            int wsCol = 3;  //start of PeriodTimes column in gvLocationBoard
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                gvLocationBoard.Columns[wsCol + wsPos].HeaderText = dr.ItemArray[1].ToString();
                gvLocationBoard.Columns[wsCol + wsPos].Visible = !gvLocationBoard.Columns[wsCol + wsPos].HeaderText.StartsWith("RollCallPeriod");

                wsPos += 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

I won't reveal the `SqlDataSource` here, but suffice to say with the `PreRender`, I can reset my `GridView` and turn ON the columns I want with the headers I want.

So the way it works is that everytime you select a different date or time periods to display as headers, it resets the GridView to the default header text and Visible="false" status before it builds the `gridview` again. Otherwise, without the `PreRender`, the GridView will have the previous data's headers as the code behind wipes the **default** settings.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code. This make invisible column if empty...

```
    protected void gridview1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Boolean hasData = false;
        for (int col = 0; col < gridview1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; col++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < gridview1.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(gridview1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Text)
                    && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gridview1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Text).Trim()))
                {
                    hasData = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!hasData)
            {
                gridview1.HeaderRow.Cells[col].Visible = false;
                for (int hiddenrows = 0; hiddenrows < gridview1.Rows.Count; hiddenrows++)
                {
                    gridview1.Rows[hiddenrows].Cells[col].Visible = false;
                }
            }

            hasData = false;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a small change to happen, it will not come under rowdatabound, first all the rows should get bound, only then could we hide that. So it will be a separate method after the grid is dataBound.

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/about, to get more understanding about questions/answers here on SO. Your contribution is not answering the question. It is more a comment, which you can add once you'll increase your reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Answer (score 0):

This was the code that worked for me when the column Id is unknown and the AutoGenerateColumns == true;

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Drawing" %>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <script runat="server">
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            data.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            data.Columns.Add("Notes", typeof(string));
            data.Columns.Add("RequestedDate", typeof(DateTime));
            for (int idx = 0; idx < 5; idx++)
            {
                DataRow row = data.NewRow();
                row["Id"] = idx;
                row["Notes"] = string.Format("Note {0}", idx);
                row["RequestedDate"] = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(idx, 0, 0, 0, 0));
                data.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            listData.DataSource = data;
            listData.DataBind();
        }

        private void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (TableCell tableCell in e.Row.Cells)
            {
                DataControlFieldCell cell = (DataControlFieldCell)tableCell;
                if (cell.ContainingField.HeaderText == "Id")
                {
                    cell.Visible = false;
                    continue;
                }
                if (cell.ContainingField.HeaderText == "Notes")
                {
                    cell.Width = 400;
                    cell.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                    continue;
                }
                if (cell.ContainingField.HeaderText == "RequestedDate")
                {
                    cell.Width = 130;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="listData" AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalAlign="Left"
            PageSize="20" OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound" EmptyDataText="No Data Available."
            Width="95%">
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't cast it like that...  System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell'

Comment: The updated code shown is a full proof that it works. The previous code example couldn't be proven on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to hide your column you can always hide the column in preRender event of the gridview . This helps you with reducing one operation for every rowdatabound event per row . You will need only one operation for prerender event .

```
protected void gvVoucherList_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int RoleID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["RoleID"]);

            switch (RoleID)
            {
                case 6: gvVoucherList.Columns[11].Visible = false;
                    break;
                case 1: gvVoucherList.Columns[10].Visible = false;
                    break;
            }
            if(hideActionColumn == "ActionSM")
            {
                gvVoucherList.Columns[10].Visible = false;
                hideActionColumn = string.Empty;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {

        }
    }
```