# How to remove the whole first column in the GridView when the value of the DropDownList Filter is rather than ALL?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following complicated asp.net code structure:

1. DropDownList as a Filter
2. Repeater
3. And inside the Repeater: I have HiddenField and GridView

I want when the value of Filter is setting to All, the fist column should be removed. The problem is I am using a StoredProcedure that takes care for generating three GridViews and this way I put the GridView inside the Repeater.

The ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDivision" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
        AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="sqlDataSourceDivision" DataTextField="DivisionName" 
        DataValueField="DivisionName"  
        Width="275px" EnableViewState="False">
        <asp:ListItem Value="%">All</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>


     <br />  <br />  
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("GroupID")%>' />

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
                                    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="kbiReport"
                                    FilterExpression="[DivisionName] like '{0}%'">

                    <FilterParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDivision" Name="DivisionName" 
                                                 PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                    </FilterParameters>

                    <SelectParameters>
                        <%--ControlParameter is linked to the HiddenField above to generate different GridView based on different values 
                            of GroupID--%>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HiddenField1" Name="GroupID" PropertyName="Value" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                <div style="width:700px; overflow:auto; overflow-y:hidden;">

                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
                                AllowSorting="True" 
                                CellPadding="3" 
                                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                                ClientIDMode="Static" class="fixedTables" Width="600" AutoGenerateColumns="true"
                                AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
                                RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                                OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnPreRender="GridView1_PreRender" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated"
                                OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold = "true" ForeColor="Black"/> 
                    <Columns>
                    </Columns>
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                </asp:GridView>
                </div>
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                           ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"
                           SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT GroupID FROM courses">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <%--Filtering by Division--%>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDataSourceDivision" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [DivisionName] FROM [Divisions]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Repeater1.DataBind();


    }


    //protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    //    {
    //        GridView gv = e.Item.FindControl("GridView1") as GridView;
    //        if (gv != null)
    //        {

    //            gv.DataBind();
    //            if (ddlDivision.SelectedValue != "ALL")
    //            {
    //                if (gv.Columns.Count > 0)
    //                    gv.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    //                else
    //                {
    //                    gv.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;
    //                    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gv.Rows)
    //                    {
    //                        gvr.Cells[0].Visible = false;
    //                    }
    //                }
    //            }

    //        }
    //    }

    //}



    //protected void ddlDivision_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //{
    //    if (ddlDivision.SelectedItem.Text == "All")
    //    {
    //        GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = true;
    //    }
    //    else
    //    {
    //        GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    //    }
    //}

    //This method is for deleting the first column in the GridView
    protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
       // e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false; // hides the first column
    }

    protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //GridView GridView1 = (GridView)sender;
        //foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
        //{
        //    if (ddlDivision.SelectedValue != "All")
        //    {
        //        gvr.Cells[0].Visible = false;

        //    }
        //}




    }


    //This function is for checking each cell in each row. 
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        //var gv = sender as GridView;
        //if (ddlDivision.SelectedValue == "All")
        //    gv.Columns[0].Visible = false;

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            foreach (TableCell c in e.Row.Cells)
            {
                // Check if the cell vlaue = Yes
                // if it is Yes, the cell will be colored with Light Green 
                if (c.Text.Contains(", Yes"))
                {
                    c.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen;
                    c.Text = "&bull;";
                }
                else if (c.Text.Contains(", NO"))
                {

                    c.Text = "";
                }
            }
        }

         //The following is for changing the color of headers in each GridView based on the value of the HiddenFild 
         //BTW, the value of the HiddenField is the value of the GroupID in Group Table in the Database 
        else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            switch (((HiddenField)((GridView)sender).Parent.FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value)
            {
                case "1":
                    for (int i = 4; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
                        e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;
                    break;

                case "2":
                    for (int i = 4; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
                        e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightYellow;
                    break;

                case "3":
                    for (int i = 4; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
                        e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
                    break;
            }
        }

    }


    protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var gv = sender as GridView;
        if (gv.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            gv.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
            gv.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
        }
    }
```

I did many tries but I failed in all of them as you see in the above behind-code. The last try was:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        GridView gv = e.Item.FindControl("GridView1") as GridView;
        if (gv != null)
        {

            gv.DataBind();
            if (ddlDivision.SelectedValue != "ALL")
            {
                if (gv.Columns.Count > 0)
                    gv.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                else
                {
                    gv.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;
                    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gv.Rows)
                    {
                        gvr.Cells[0].Visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

and I failed. **Could anyone help me with this issue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want when the value of Filter is setting to All, the fist column
>   should be removed.

If this is the case, surely you want this:

```
if (ddlDivision.SelectedValue == "ALL") { // hide column 0 }
```

rather than this:

```
if (ddlDivision.SelectedValue != "ALL") { // hide column 0 }
```

Using `gv.Columns[0].Visible = false;`  should work fine assuming you have a correct reference to your `gv` object **and** your GridView has its `AutoGenerateColumns` property set to `false`.

You must ensure this as `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` is the GridView default, and in this case `GridView.Columns.Count` will be always be 0. If you attempt to reference `.Columns[x]` it will throw an 'Index was out of range.' exception.

More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3819831/441574

**Update:**

As you're using `AutoGenerateColumns="true"`, you could hide your column(s) using the `RowDataBound` event of your GridView:

**Create Event Handler:**

If your GridView is **static** (declared on your .aspx page), add this to its declaration: `OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound"`

If your GridView is **created programatically**, add the RowDataBound event handler: `gv.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(gv_RowDataBound);`

**Then add your RowDataBound event:**

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{ 
    ...
    if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Pager) 
    {
        if (ddlDivision.SelectedItem.Text != "ALL")
        {
           // only check for pager row, all other rows including header/footer should be hidden
           e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false; 
        }
    }
    ...    
}
```

Comment: You are right. I am using (AutoGenerateColumns="true"), because I am binding a GridView to a storedProcedure and if I set it to false, nothing will be displayed in the GridView. So how to solve this issue?

Comment: Ok the column now is deleted but how I can delete it just when the value of the DroupDonwList filter is setting to ALL. Please help me with this issue because this is the most difficult part to me.

Comment: And by the way, I really appreciate your help and explanation. Please keep it up.

Comment: No problem, check my edit, you can wrap your row events in an if.

Comment: Thanks a lot but what you did is hiding the column when the value is of the filter is "ALL". What I want is display the first column only when the value of the filter is "ALL". How to do that? I put it as (ddlDivision.SelectedValue != "ALL") but it did not work and I don't know why.

Comment: Maybe try: if (ddlDivision.SelectedItem.Text != "ALL") as seen in the updated example.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. I really appreciate your efforts and work. I got a benefit from you man.