# gridview hide column after databind or before

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I have dataset as you can see below.I want to hide first three columns. But the way I do below doesnt work. How can I do hide them?

```
// Read all posts and fill  gridview
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    DbCommand dbCommand2;
    dbCommand2 = db.GetStoredProcCommand("PC_Select_News");
    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand2, "UserId", DbType.Guid, new Guid(Session["SessionUserId"].ToString().Trim()));
    DataSet ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand2);
    grid_all_posts.DataSource = ds;

    grid_all_posts.DataBind();
    grid_all_posts.Columns[1].Visible = false;
    grid_all_posts.Columns[2].Visible = false;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819247/gridview-hide-column-by-code

Comment: I solved it. You should use the code below and in aspx file, you should put ondatabound event handler in gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using () instead of [].

gvMyGrid.Columns(0).Visible == false;

The above works fine for me.