# How to hide column in data table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have `DataTable` which I filled using an SQL Query. Then I filled the `GridView` with the `DataTable`.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Load(reader);
gvAktivne.DataSource = table;
gvAktivne.DataBind();
```

This works fine but now I want to hide the first column. When I add this:

```
gvAktivne.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

I get an `IndexOutOfRange` exception.
Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Could you please confirm if your datasource has valid data Rows.Count > 0.

Comment: Remove column from the DataTable instance before binding it to GridView.

Comment: answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3819831/542398

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GridView Hide Column by code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819247/gridview-hide-column-by-code)

Answer (score 9):

This may work for you:

```
DataTable data;
data.Columns[0].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the problem statement it appears you have `AutoGenerateColumns` set to `true`. This is going to be problematic when you want to hide columns. You need to make sure that you issue that line of code **after** the `DataBind()` and I would do it in `OnPreRender`.

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    gvAktivne.Columns[0].Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 protected void  GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
      e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
 }
```