# Hiding Autogenerated gridview column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to hide a column that is generated automatically in a grid view..
can any one suggest me how to do it..

**my code **

```
public page_load
{
private void BindGrid()
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int16));// here it produce error as Field name ID already exists 
        dt.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("DateOfBirth", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Occupation", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("State", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("PostCode", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Mobile", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("CustomerType", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("BusinessName", typeof(string));        
        CexCustomer.DataBind();        
    }
}

protected void btn_ShowCust_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(Int16)));
                      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FirstName", typeof(string)));
                      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("LastName", typeof(string)));
                      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DateOfBirth", typeof(string)));
                      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Occupation", typeof(string)));
                      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Address", typeof(string)));
                      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("State", typeof(string)));
                      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PostCode", typeof(string)));
                      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Country", typeof(string)));
                      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Email", typeof(string)));
                      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Mobile", typeof(string)));
                      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CustomerType", typeof(string)));
                      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BusinessName", typeof(string)));                         


                      DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                      int countvalue = myojb.Count;

                      for (int i = 0; i < countvalue; i++)
                      {
                          dt.Rows.Add(
                                     myojb[i].id,
                                     myojb[i].firstName,
                                     myojb[i].lastName,
                                     myojb[i].dob.ToUniversalTime().ToString("dd/MM/yyy"),
                                     myojb[i].occupation,
                                     myojb[i].address,
                                     myojb[i].state,
                                     myojb[i].postCode,
                                     myojb[i].country.ToUpper(),
                                     myojb[i].email,
                                     myojb[i].mobileNumber,
                                     myojb[i].customertype,
                                     myojb[i].businessName
                                     );

                      }
                      CexCustomer.Visible = true;                         
                      CexCustomer.DataSource = dt;
                      CexCustomer.Columns[12].Visible = false;//hide business name..
                      CexCustomer.DataBind();

}
```

while runtime i need to hide the Businessdetails can any one suggest how to solve this issue..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819247/gridview-hide-column-by-code

Answer (score 0):

In your Row Data Bound event...

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[12].Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index  produced this error..

Answer (score 0):

Thank-You for your answers..
I just set my Auto generated columns to false, and followed my coding process..it works good..