# How to hide GridView Coumn[1]?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to hide the gridview coumn[1]. But it shows error like

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
the collection parameter name:index.
```

How can I perform this. I surfed a lot in internet but I didnt get a proper solution. My code I mentioned below.It is a web based platform.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   if (!IsPostBack)
     {
      qry = "select Id,Name,Age,Sex,Dob from Sample where Code='123';
      dr = conn.query(qry);
      GridView1.DataSource = dr;
      GridView1.DataBind();
      GridView1.Columns[1].Visible = false;
      }
 }
```

In this same way column[0] is hiding.
My grid view is

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HorizontalAlign="Center" runat="server" 
      onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField>
          <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"
                   CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>'>Delete</asp:LinkButton>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Where is column 1 in your gridview?

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ,column1 value will add from database(from query result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [RowDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to hide a column. You can use the code below

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;
}
```

Similar question on SO

1. [GridView Hide Column by code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819247/gridview-hide-column-by-code)

Comment: I want to do it in page load

Comment: That's hiding the individual cells, not the entire column, so it's not *exactly* what is being asked for, is it?

Comment: @Eilon row data bound will be called for each row rather than individual cell.

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ, it works only if  only the RowDataBound triggered. I want to hide the  first column when the page is load

Comment: So why don't you add this event in your grid?

Comment: @SaraJohn by the way why do you want to hide the column?

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ yes it will be called once for each row, but my point is that hiding the cells within each row is not the same as hiding the entire column, thought on the surface it might appear to render the same UI.

Comment: @Eilon as I don't see the `second column` there in the grid this might cause the error.

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ, It is an ID, I am using this as command argument..But i dont want to display it

Comment: @SaraJohn I don't see the second column in your grid. You can also use [DataKeyName](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23833/DataKeyNames) instead of hiding the column.